# Equality with norms of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I have a problem with prooving of following equality:
$$\|E(I-\frac{ss^T}{s^Ts})\|_F^2=\|E\|_F^2-\frac{\|Es\|^2_2}{s^Ts},$$
where $E\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $0\neq s\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I tried to enumerate it as a sums  from both sides but I've got this 
$$ 
\sum_{k,l}(e_{kl}-\frac{1}{\sum_js_j^2}\sum_ie_{kl}s_is_l)^2
$$ 
on RHS and this 
$$
\sum_{k,l}(e_{kl})^2-\frac{1}{\sum_js_j^2}\sum_k(\sum_ie_{ki}s_i)^2
$$
on LHS. Is that a right way to proove it? I am desperate because I've spent several hours solving it and I've no idea how to proceed. Thank you for any hint.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=s/\|s\|$ (hence $u$ is a unit vector and $u^Tu=1$). The equality you want to prove is equivalent to
$$
\left\|E(I-uu^T)\right\|_F^2=\|E\|_F^2-\|Eu\|^2_2.
$$
To prove this, use the facts that $\|X\|_F^2=\operatorname{tr}(XX^T)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(XY)=\operatorname{tr}(YX)$ for any two matrices $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Then I have $$tr((E-Euu^T)(E-Euu^T)^T)=tr((E-Euu^T)(E^T-u u^TE^T))=tr(EE^T-Euu^TE^T)=tr(EE^T)-tr((Eu)(Eu)^T)=\|E\|_F^2-\|Eu\|_F^2=\|E\|_F^2-\|Eu\|_2^2.$$ Am I right? And there is one more thing. Doesn't such a choice of vector $u$ cause loss of generality?

Comment: It's mostly correct, but I believe the second term is better handled as follows: $tr((Eu)(Eu)^T)=tr((Eu)^T(Eu))=(Eu)^T(Eu)=\|Eu\|_2^2$. And what do you mean by a loss of generality? $u$ is a general unit vector, isn't it?

Comment: Great. I was thinking about my "generality problem" for a while, now it is clear. Thank you for help.